# How to add two lists into dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
i=["Pin","Type","value"]
j=[["abc","input","1234"],["xyz","output","2345"],["pqr","input","567"]]
z=dict(zip(i,j))
```

And I want to join them into dictionary, so that my output should be like this,

```
z={
   "Pin": ["abc","xyz","pqr"],
   "Type": ["input","input","input"],
   "value": ["1234","2345","567"]
  }
```

How can I add this two lists into dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> dict(zip(i,zip(*j)))
{'Type': ('input', 'output', 'input'), 'value': ('1234', '2345', '567'), 'Pin': ('abc', 'xyz', 'pqr')}
```

Or if you really want lists,

```
>>> dict(zip(i,map(list,zip(*j))))
{'Type': ['input', 'output', 'input'], 'value': ['1234', '2345', '567'], 'Pin': ['abc', 'xyz', 'pqr']}
```

[`izip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), [`imap`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap), etc may be appropriate if the lists were longer.