# Generating a hierarchical file from webscraped comments and outputting as JSON

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I've webscraped some data from a forum(using Python), and have popped it in a dictionary which looks like this:

```
thread = {"1.Init_Post": init_post,
         "2.Time_Posted": time_posted,
         "3.URL": url,
         "4.Discussion_Posts": discussion_posts,
         "5.Discussion_Post_Times": post_dates}
```

It contains the initial post, the time the initial post was posted, the URL of the original post, the corresponding discussion posts, and the time each of the discussion posts were posted.

An example of the output from one discussion is:

```
{'1.Init_Post': u'I purchased a piece of land over 12 years ago which did not come with any title guarantee. I now wish to register this with the land registry. Does anyone know how I do this please?  thanks so much',
 '2.Time_Posted': '17/08/17 22:47',
 '3.URL': 'http://www.thelawforum.co.uk/how-register-land-unregistered-title',
 '4.Discussion_Posts': [u'How did you manage that? Registration has been compulsory for years. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/first-registrations/practice-...',
  u'I read that it had to be done within 3 months and that regime started in 1998?  i have another look at the emails from the solicitor when it was purchased in 2005. The solicitor said the land registry had refused to register the land because its previous use of grazing livestock and cutting hay was not sufficiently strong to warrant granting of title. So we purchased indemnity insurance and was told to wait 10/12 years before trying again. was this advice incorrect?  thanks',
  u'sounds about right. Try with LR again.',
  u'Registration has been must for any land you buy from someone. How did you manage this issue from last 12 years. You need to consult a good lawyer. Or need to create documents as soon as possible.'],
 '5.Discussion_Post_Times': ['18/08/17 08:19',
  '18/08/17 09:42',
  '18/08/17 13:25',
  '02/09/17 06:14']}
```

What I want is a hierarchical file (which I can turn into a JSON), which looks like this:

```
{'1.Init_Post': u'I purchased a piece of land over 12 years ago which did not come with any title guarantee. I now wish to register this with the land registry. Does anyone know how I do this please?  thanks so much',
'2.Time_Posted': '17/08/17 22:47',
'3.URL': 'http://www.thelawforum.co.uk/how-register-land-unregistered-title',
'4.Discussion':[
    {'a.Discussion_Post':u'How did you manage that? Registration has been compulsory for years. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/first-registrations/practice-...',
     'b.Discussion_Post_Time':'18/08/17 08:19'},
    {'a.Discussion_Post':u'I read that it had to be done within 3 months and that regime started in 1998?  i have another look at the emails from the solicitor when it was purchased in 2005. The solicitor said the land registry had refused to register the land because its previous use of grazing livestock and cutting hay was not sufficiently strong to warrant granting of title. So we purchased indemnity insurance and was told to wait 10/12 years before trying again. was this advice incorrect?  thanks',
     'b.Discussion_Post_Time':'18/08/17 09:42'},
    {'a.Discussion_Post':u'sounds about right. Try with LR again.',
     'b.Discussion_Post_Time':'18/08/17 13:25'},
    {'a.Discussion_Post':'Registration has been must for any land you buy from someone. How did you manage this issue from last 12 years. You need to consult a good lawyer. Or need to create documents as soon as possible.',
     'b.Discussion_Post_Time':'02/09/17 06:14'}
]
}
```

I've looked at this question: [Translate a table to a hierarchical dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193235/translate-a-table-to-a-hierarchical-dictionary). But I think I can be more efficient than turning it into a table and then into a hierarchical structure. Any suggestions for how to appreciated!

Comment: You need to show some effort please. How about [adding the two lists into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502197/how-to-add-two-lists-into-dictionary) and embedding it in the original dictionary under the `Discussion` key? or appending them to that list in your case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `zip` the two keys in a new `'4.Discussion'` key, then delete them.

```
thread['4.Discussion'] = [
    {'a.Discussion_Post':i[0], 'b.Discussion_Post_Time':i[1]} 
    for i in zip(thread['4.Discussion_Posts'], thread['5.Discussion_Post_Times'])
]
del thread['4.Discussion_Posts']
del thread['5.Discussion_Post_Times']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
'4.Discussion': [{'a.Discussion_Post': i, 'b.Discussion_Post_Time': j} for i, j in zip(out['4.Discussion_Posts'], out['5.Discussion_Post_Times'])]
```